# How can I print a list recursively without use any built-in function in Prolog?

Tags: prolog

I'm new to Prolog. I understand the fundamental recursion in Prolog, such as append, member.

I'm wondering how can I print a list recursively without using built-in function in Prolog.

Can anyone help me with that?

Comment: If you just want to print a list then that's got no need of `append` or `member`. Exactly how do you want the printed list to look? It would help if you could show what the query would look like as well as desired output.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Most predicates that involve processing a list will devolve into a rule for the empty list and a rule for handling one item and recursively handling the rest of the list. As a template, it would look something like this:

```
pred([])     :- ??? % empty case
pred([X|Xs]) :- 
   ???              % handle X
   pred(Xs).        % recur for the tail of the list
```

Notice we're just using the definition of a list here, no special predicates required. See if this is enough for you to figure out the solution, and if you do, post it as an answer.